# PHP mssql_connect issue

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm running this php file:

```
<?php
$link = mssql_connect('db1.peanut.butter.com:3184', 'user', 'pass');
?>
```

and getting this error:

```
Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: db1.peanut.butter.com:3184 in /tmp/query.php on line 3
```

The server is up and running, and I was able to connect and query it from the SSMS.

How should I write the server in the `mssql_connect` command?
Full name? Just 'db1'? No port?

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to specify instance of your database. "db1.peanut.butter.com:3184\SQLEXPRESS" <-- It's an exemple. 
You should don't use `mssql_connect` function, it's remove in PHP7 use sqlsrv_connect instead : http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Comment: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Comment: @Thomas Rollet, I'm still getting the same error: `Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: db1.peanut.butter.com:3184\INST1 in /tmp/query.php on line 3`

Comment: Look at this  : http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php

Comment: I'm unable to perform any installation/modifications on the server since it's not mine.

Comment: So maybe you can't access to this database through the network...

Answer (score -1):

This function was [removed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php) from PHP **7.0.0**

Check if that might be the case.

Comment: If he used PHP 7 he had this error : "Undefined function mssql_connect()".
Here it's a problem to communicate with database.